# Ansible - установка Apache или httpd в зависимости от дистрибутива

Tags: ansible

Подскажите пожалуйста, как по условию (тип ОС) в Ansible выбрать либо Apache2, либо httpd, Ansible:

```
 ---
- hosts: test
  remote_user: frolov
  become: yes
      #  become_method: sudo
      #
  tasks:
  - name: Debug
    debug: msg={{ ansible_os_family }}

  - set_fact: package_name=apache2
    when: ansible_os_family == "Debian"

  - set_fact: package_name=httpd
    when: ansible_os_family == "Redhat"


  - name: Update cache packages
    apt:
      update_cache: yes
      cache_valid_time: 3600
    #              #
    #  - name: Final_packet
    # debug: msg={{ package_name }}

  - name: Install Apache2
    apt:
      name: "{{ item }}"
      state: latest
      with_items:
        - "{{ package_name }}"
      when: ansible_os_family == "Debian"

  - name: Install httpd2
    apt:
      name: "{{ item }}"
      state: latest
      with_items:
        - "{{ package_name }}"
      when: ansible_os_family == "Redhat"
```

При запуске данного плейбука получаю ошибку

```
 fatal: [10.101.251.157]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'item' is undefined\n\nThe error appears to have been in '/etc/ansible/playbook/apache_install.yml': line 26, column 5, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n  - name: Install Apache2\n    ^ here\n\nexception type: <class 'ansible.errors.AnsibleUndefinedVariable'>\nexception: 'item' is undefined"}
    to retry, use: --limit @/etc/ansible/playbook/apache_install.retry
```

Ansible  2.4.3.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Разделите установку на два скрипта - один для Redhat-based, другой - для debian.

```
---

- name: install php5.6
  include_tasks: centos_php56.yml
  when: (ansible_distribution == "CentOS") and (php.version == "5.6")

- name: install php7.0
  include_tasks: centos_php70.yml
  when: (ansible_distribution == "CentOS") and (php.version == "7.0")
```

Для debian используйте apt, для Centos yum. И просто прописывайте нужные пакеты, например для Centos:

```
- name: install php56
  yum: name={{ item }} state=latest
  with_items:
    - php56w
    - php56w-opcache
    - php56w-pdo
    - php56w-mysql
    - php56w-mbstring
    - php56w-mcrypt
    - php56w-pear
    - php56w-pecl-apcu
    - php56w-gd    
  notify: restart httpd
```

И да, я рекоменую сразу где вы устанавливаете пакеты использовать with_items, даже если у вас один пакет - сразу закладываетесь на возможное расширение, а не просто ставите пакеты по одному:

```
- name: install php
  yum: name=php state=latest
  notify: restart httpd
```

От чего происходит ошибка у вас. Когда вы используете команду yum в ней запрещено указывать when. (С apt видимо тоже самое) Поэтому вариант:

```
- set_fact:
    package_name=git
- name: yum install packages
  yum:
    name: "{{ package_name }}"
    state: latest
    when:
      ansible_os_family == "Centos"
```

Выбивает ошибку

```
TASK [git : yum install packages]
**********************************************
fatal: [server.company.tld]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "failed": true, "msg": "Unsupported parameters for (yum) module: when Supported parameters include: allow_downgrade,conf_file,disable_gpg_check,disablerepo,enablerepo,exclude,install_repoquery,installroot,list,name,security,skip_broken,state,update_cache,validate_certs"}
```

И такую же ошибку вызовет прямое указание пакета без доп. переменных:

```
---

- name: yum install packages
  yum:
    name: git
    state: latest
    when:
      ansible_os_family == "Centos"
```

Поэтому избавляемся от when (разбиваем на два скрипта, как я показывал в начале)

После этого установка пакета:

```
---

- set_fact:
    package_name="git"
- name: yum install packages
  yum:
    name: "{{ item }}"
    state: latest
  with_items:
   - "{{ package_name }}"
```

(обратите внимание на каком уровне отступов находится with_items - не на уровне name и state, а на уровне yum)

Нескольких пакетов:

```
- set_fact:
    packages={"git","ansible"}
- name: yum install packages
  yum:
    name: "{{ item }}"
    state: latest
  with_items: "{{ packages }}"
```

Но в принципе нет никакого резона устанавливать дополнительную переменную, чтобы потом её использовать - пишите сразу:

```
- name: yum install packages
  yum:
    name: "{{ item }}"
    state: latest
  with_items:
    - git
```

или

```
- name: yum install packages
  yum:
    name: "{{ item }}"
    state: latest
  with_items:
    - git
    - ansible
```

Comment: Спасибо, попробую! Но в моем случае - в чем ошибка?

Comment: Попробовал, не работает, также ругается на кавычки The offending line appears to be:

    apt:
      name: {{ item }}
             ^ here
We could be wrong, but this one looks like it might be an issue with
missing quotes.  Always quote template expression brackets when they
start a value. For instance:

    with_items:
      - {{ foo }}

Should be written as:

    with_items:
      - "{{ foo }}"

Comment: Переделал, не работает(

Comment: Мммм... действительно, скрипт скомпилировался, но дойдя до шага рухнул. Сейчас, надо переключить голову с c# на линукс....

Comment: А, ну понятно. Вторую ошибку я у вас из скрипта скопипастил - уровень для with_items не тот

Comment: Спасибо, действительно, в уровнях была проблема!

Comment: @Kallipso И с уровнем when такая же проблема.